# How to check using expression if process variable is exist in camunda workflow?

Tags: bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler

I want to check at exclusive gateway if processInstance exist.I can check if the value of processInstance is set to null  or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to check in expression like below

${execution.getVariable('xyz') == null}

execution.getVariable() method works both in service task and expression as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use a service task before the gateway that executes a process instance query and stores the result in a process variable, then, in the gateway, just check that variable (true/false).

Comment: But is it correct approach, Is there any way to check in expression directly without having a extra task for this.

Comment: ${execution.getProcessEngineServices().createProcessInstanceQuery() .... count() > 0}

Comment: I have found the way and posted my answer.

Comment: Ah, ok, I thought you wanted to query for existence of another processInstance ...